# Directional Vector Word Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, vectors

So here's the problem: Suppose a bird is flying NE at 5m/s into a headwind blowing at 2m/s 30° SE. Find the NE direction in which the bird **was** flying and it's resulting speed in the east direction.

What I basically have set up so far looks like this (I tried to make it look as clear as possible but i'm not an artist lol):

[image: Imgur Link]

I know that  I'm trying to find for the angle $\theta$ and also the magnitude of the vector (b+w) which I assume is going to be the resulting speed of the bird. Unfortunately, I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding the wording of the problem so I have no idea if what I have set up is even close to right and, even if it is, I have no idea what my next step should be.

I'd really appreciate any help :)

Comment: Look through the related questions in the handy list at right for ideas.

Comment: so you mean the direction before the headwind hit the bird

Comment: yup I think the problem asks for the angle before the headwind hit the bird but the speed it's asking for is after the headwind hit the bird.

Answer (score 1):

The basic equation is ground speed =air speed + wind speed.  You are given the ground speed of the bird.  Is the NE in the problem $45^\circ$?  I don't see any other way to interpret it.  Then just subtract the wind speed to get the air speed.  You can split both vectors into N/S and E components and do your arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but, I think that's for the physics side of things and this is for a pre-calc class. Would you know how I might be able to solve this using vectors?

Comment: What I described is a vector solution.  You just subtract them.

Comment: Ok now I think I see what you mean. By air speed you were referring to the resulting speed after the bird is hit by headwind.

Comment: No, air speed is the speed relative to the air.  Although it is called speed it can be (as here) a vector.  It is the speed the bird feels it is flying.  You add the wind to that to get the speed relative to the ground.

Comment: Finally got it now, thanks.